# How to change Google Doc displayed in PHP page when user clicks map area through ImageMapster?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-docs

I'am new to js and php and I'm really sorry if I'm not seeing something obvious. Here's the situation followed by the question:

I have a map1.png displayed and when user hovers on an area of that image, the correspondent area of a second image (map2.png) is shown. I got it working using imagemapster. Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#areas').mapster({
    singleSelect : false,
    clickNavigate: true,
    render_highlight : { altImage : 'Images/map2.png' },
     mapKey: 'module',
    fill : true, altImage : 'Images/map2.png',
    fillOpacity : 1,
});
});
```

and here's the markup for the image:

```
<img id="areas" src="Images/map.png" width="927" height="704" alt="Mapa pedagógico" usemap="#areas">
```

and for one of the many areas mapped:

```
<map name="areas">
<area module="social" shape="circle" coords="463,461,63" href="programmation-noob-social.html" alt="social"/>
```

Here's the thing as it is: http://www.eloquatranslations.com/mapa-pedagogico.php

Note the page also shows a Google spreadsheet. What I want to do is find a way to change that Google document when user clicks one of the areas from the image. Each area of the img map should correspond to a different spreadsheet.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I gave a *show* id to the iframe, and emptied the *src* tag, so it can be populated by my script.

```
<iframe id="show" width="100%" height="610" src=""></iframe>
```

In the js script, I used an *onClick* function, which creates a variable that will be set by a second function *findDoc*. This function creates the findDoc variable based on the *data.key* and puts that in the *show* iframe, in the *src* tag.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#areas').mapster({
onClick : findDoc,
singleSelect : true,
clickNavigate: false,
render_highlight : { altImage : 'Images/map2.png' },
 mapKey: 'module',
fill : true, altImage : 'Images/map2.png',
fillOpacity : 1
});
});
function findDoc(data){
var srcBegin = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/';
var srcEnd = '/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false';
var srcMid = data.key;
$('#show').attr('src',(srcBegin+srcMid+srcEnd));
}
```

Then I set the *module* keys in each area of the map to the correspondent Google Doc id:

```
<area module="1q7tRr6IkCDjS_mmDRWCj-ViExIPQn8imOu6MTiwKyWw" shape="circle" coords="463,461,63" href="#" alt="social"/>
```

And it works fine.

It may seem simple for real programmers... For me, it was a real joy to get it running! :)